# Rough-in pex line

Tags: plumbing, pex, rough-in

I have plans of building a bathroom on the second floor next year. I am currently re-modelling the first floor and I would like to get the plumbing for the new bathroom in place so that I do not have to do any drywall work next year.

Can I rough in hot & cold water supply pex lines in the same stud cavity (marked with arrow in the picture) where there is a drain pipe running ? I've run out of space in the other studs.

[image: Bare Walls]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  There is no code preventing this.  Also this makes sense because all of your leak issues are in the same place.

One other bit of advice - before you close up the wall get rid of the the metal and cast iron venting/drains.  It will cost you $20 and the pvc will have less problems and last longer (and won't be flagged on future home inspection).

[Also electric should be stapled above outlet (yellow romex).

Comment: Thank you ! You're right.. I do have to replace the metal drain pipes.

Comment: @bib - easy to catch after I have been flagged by inspectors... maybe 20 times haha.  I just carry a hammer and staples with me when doing my electrical inspections.